# Can you tell how similar 2 songs sound from their waveform?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but can you tell how similar 2 songs sound from their waveform?

For example, could you search for a certain pattern in a audio file's waveform to tell if it was metal, rock or classical music?

Comment: first question: yes you could ;-) second question: Well, metal will be amplitude at the top all the time, rock almost all the time and classical music will show some dynamics, and even some gaps (= breaks)...

Comment: I'd say this isnt a good idea particularly given how much compression is used in most mastering,